# querying primary keys from a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to MySQL and I am struggling querying or referencing primary key's by foreign keys specified in a table. Can someone please explain how to do this in fairly simple terms, as everything I've searched is a bit hard to understand considering majority of others have allot more MySQL knowledge then me.

Let's just assume these are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer(
    custID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    custLname varchar(30),
    custAdd varchar(100),
    custSuburb varchar(30),
    custPcode varchar(4),
    custState varChar(20),
    custPhone varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (custID)
)ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tour(
    DailyTourID int,
    tourDate DATE,
    tourTime TIME,
    tourName varchar(30),
    tourDriverID int,
    tourBusID varchar(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (DailyTourID, tourDate),
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TourCustLink(
    TourCustLinkID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TourID int,
    TourDate DATE,
    customerID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (TourCustLinkID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TourID, TourDate) REFERENCES tour(DailyTourID, tourDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer(custID)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I am aware this is a pretty bad example, but lets say I want to show the custLname, custAdd, custPhone and tourDates for each customer. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @ http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) them:

```
SELECT 
  c.custLname,
  c.custAdd,
  c.custPhone,
  t.TourDate,
  t.TourName,
  ...
FROM TourCustLink   AS tl 
INNER JOIN Customer AS c  ON tl.customerId = c.custID
INNER JOIN Tour     AS t  ON tl.tourID     = t.DailyTourID 
                         AND tl.tourDate   = t.tourDate;
```

You might also need to use `OUTER JOIN`s (`LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`) instead of `INNER JOIN`, in case you want to include those unmatched rows.

For more information about the `JOIN` types see this article:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)